# Как связать create-react-app с back-end сервером?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

Всем привет, часа 3 сижу не могу связать реакт приложение с сервером на node (express)
В документации пишут прописать proxy в package.json.

```
"name": "marmelad",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
```

Так и сделал.

Вот мой ajax

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const userLoginRequest = (data) => dispatch => {
      // return axios.post('/api/auth', data);
      return fetch('/api/auth', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'text/html' 
            },
            body: data
      })
}
```

Использовал axios, но уже с фетчем пытаюсь, так в документации.
Запросы все равно уходят на localhost:3000, вместо 3001.

На серверной части все прозрачно

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
// import cors from 'cors';

// import users from './routes/users';
import auth from './routes/auth';

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
})

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3001));

// Express only serves static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}

app.use('/api/auth', auth);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Find the server at: http://localhost:${app.get('port')}/`);
});
```

auth.js

import express from 'express';

```
let router = express.Router();

router.post('/api/auth', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
})

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Читайте внимательнее документацию.

> The development server will only attempt to send requests without a text/html accept header to the proxy.

Исправьте заголовок 'Content-Type' и всё заработает.